# Get everything before nth occurrence of delimiter on hive

Tags: regex, string, hive, substring, hiveql

I already search on many regex matcher, I have string like this:

```
KRW3TR.899877.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*
```

I already make extraction with this, but it failed.
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(acolumn,'^([^\.]+)\.?',2)`

What I want is
`KRW3TR.899877`

How to regexp extract/ trim/ regexp replace this?

Any help/ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring_index`, which returns the substring before a given number of occurrences (2) of a given delimiter (.):

```
SELECT substring_index(
    'KRW3TR.899877.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*', 
    '.',
    2
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regexp:

```
select regexp_extract('KRW3TR.899877.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*',
                      '^([^.]*\\.[^.]*)' 
                      ,1) --extract group number 1
```

Regexp meaning:

```
        ^ - beginning of the string anchor
        [^.]* - not a dot 0 or more times
        \\. - dot
        [^.]* - not a dot 0 or more times
```

Result:

```
KRW3TR.899877
```